# laravel get all models with relations and the relations of these relations

Tags: php, laravel

block has two relations

> 1- one to many with region
>
> 2- one to many with seat

and the region has one to many relation with seat too so

> 3- region has one to many relation with seat too

this code

```
 $block=Block::with('regions','seats')->where('id',$blockId)->get();
```

will return this , it doesn't send regions relations

```
0 => Block {#457 ▼
  #relations: array:2 [▼
    "regions" => Collection {#460 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Region {#463 ▼
          #relations: []
        }
      ]
    }
    "seats" => Collection {#471 ▶}
```

here the region has many seats and this code will nor return region seats.
i can just get the block regions and seats while regions has many seats too.

should i get all regions id first and then try to get it all seats ? , is there any way to this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$block = Block::with('regions.seats', 'seats')->where('id', $blockId)->get();
```